# How to prove equality of the cardinality two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The question states:

Prove that $|(0,1)| = |(-e, \pi)|$.

I am assuming this has something to do with the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröeder Theorem, but I don't really have a good understanding as to how to apply it.

How would I show this proof?

Comment: You can write down an explicit bijection.

Comment: What do you mean 'explicit' bijection.. by showing it is injective and surjective on both sides?

Comment: There are probably infinitely many other duplicates. I'm too lazy to find them now. Your turn.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Construct a straight line connecting point  $(0,-e)$ and point $(1,\pi)$.

Comment: What exactly does this mean?

Comment: given $2$ points on the plane, construct a line connecting them. It might lead you to a solution.